# how to make a listbox column wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid, devexpress

I created a gridcontrol with multiple types of columns . I want, when I click on a specific cell( from my listboxedit column created), a listbox to be shown. How can I do that? I don't want the listbox to be in cell.

Comment: Catch the Click event at GridControl's level and show your ListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                     <TextBlock Content="{Binding Title}"/>
                     <Popup IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Path=IsSelected}">
                           <ListBox>
                                <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
                            </ListBox>
                      </Popup>
                  </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```